# Problem with certificates

Tags: certificates

I'm with problems with ca-certificates. Every site that I try to access ask me for a confirmation of the certification and my update is not working 100% too

```
$ sudo rm -rf /etc/ssl/certs/*
$ sudo update-ca-certificates Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 152 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.
$ sudo apt-get update
[...]                                
Err private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages              
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt    CRLfile: none
Err private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Ign private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Fetched 1,118 kB in 44s (24.9 kB/s)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*You* removed all certificates yourself when you ran `sudo rm -rf /etc/ssl/certs/*`. That broke your system. One thing you can do to fix this is to reinstall the package they come from:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

This should be relatively safe. If that doesn't work, you may need to purge the package out and reinstall it but don't attempt this if you currently have broken packages.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
# stop if you saw any errors

sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer mirabilios! I don't know what happened, I didn't anything else to try to solve the problem, but few days later my connections back to work as usual. May it was a problem in server that was fixed, I don't know. But, thank you for try to help!

Comment: @Oli --reinstall only works for things that are not dpkg conffiles. But (I just looked on 14.04) `ca-certificates` indeed does not ship those files as dpkg conffiles, so your edit is probably safe. (Maintainer scripts and debconf caching might still interfere, but probably not in this example.) So, thanks.

Comment: Additionally, the `/etc/ssl/certs` is collated using the `update-ca-certificates` command. I would expect updates to `ca-certificates` to trigger this but you might have to run it afterwards manually.

Comment: @Oli from reading the `postinst` it should be triggered.

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates did the deed. Thank you very much!