# How to install traceroute in Linux?

Tags: traceroute

I am currently taking a Controlled Assessment, and this is one of the tasks.

> Make sure that you have the program `traceroute` installed. (Install
>   it if necessary.)

I went on https://www.codeground.net/howto/traceroute-is-not-installed-by-default-on-ubuntu-replaced-by-mtr/, and it told me to use `sudo apt-get install traceroute`,so I tried that, but it comes up with an errror message when I try it.

If you have any solutions I would be very grateful! :-)

Edit: I just used anand's answer, but it says:

`E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
 E: Unable  to lock the administration  directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?`

I am unaware of what this means, so can someone please help.

Edit 2:I tried anand's updated answer, but the error message that comes up is:

`Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Edit 3: anand told me to add the logs, so [here they are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCxgW.png).

Comment: What error does it come up with?

Comment: @Arronical It says `Unable to fetch some archives,maybe run apt-get update or try with -- fix missing?` I don't know what that means because I am new to Linux, so don't judge my stupidity.

Comment: Don't worry, it'd be useful to [edit] the question to include the error, as comments can get cleaned up down the line. Unfortunately I'm no expert on `apt` stuff, but your question will likely get more help with that included. Try `sudo apt-get update` before trying to install. If you get errors, add them to your question too :)

Comment: You sure you wrote `sudo` before `apt-get install --fix-missing`?

Comment: @M.Becerra I tried anand's answer again, and it worked, but when I typed  `sudo apt-get install traceroute`, it came up with the same error.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Info: In linux equivalent of traceroute is pre-installed:

```
tracepath
```

Solution of your error message:

```
   sudo apt-get install --fix-missing  
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install traceroute
```

Comment: I have updated the answer, please have a look

Comment: provide the failed logs

Comment: the entire logs which comes afte running update command.  Baically that error is because of ppa or apt repository.  
for reference : http://xmodulo.com/how-to-fix-apt-get-update-error-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: I added the failed logs in the question, please have a look.

Comment: Please look here, also make sure your date is correct over pc.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/420860/problem-with-certificates

Comment: I also had to put sudo after the && to make it work: "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install traceroute"

Answer (score 5):

There are several Ubuntu packages that provide [traceroute](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=traceroute&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. What they all appear to have in common is you must [enable the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) to install them.

Your lock errors mean that something else has locked apt. Usually the software center is still open and closing it will resolve the issue.

Comment: You do realize I'm doing this on Linux, right?

Comment: @CodingTeen2017 I would hope so. The name of this site is AskUbuntu.com Ubuntu is a variant of Linux. My answer is on topic for the site. If you are using some other variant of Linux perhaps your question is off-topic for this site. Please [edit] the output of `lsb_release -a` into your post

Answer (score 3):

```
$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-221-18-242 4.15.0-1057-aws #59-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 4 10:02:00 UTC 
2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install inetutils-traceroute

$ traceroute --version
traceroute (GNU inetutils) 1.9.4
```

Comment: Why did you include the uname command? Also, you did not answer the users question about why they are receiving the error when trying to install traceroute.

Comment: I have added uname because working solution can vary across versions. Sometimes working solution is better than investigations of issues and can give more insight to someone solving his stuff.