# traceroute is not installing on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, ip-address, traceroute

I tried to use `traceroute` for my networking project. But whenever I tried to install `traceroute` it shows that

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
You might want to run 'apt--fix-broken install' to correct these.  
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
code : Depends: libgconf-2-4 but it is not going to be installed  
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I followed this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891179/how-to-install-traceroute-in-linux). But again it is not successfully installed and shows that,

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  code : Depends: libgconf-2-4 but it is not installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Now my question is, How I can install the `traceroute` in my ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt --fix-broken install` like the output suggests?

Comment: thank you @waltinator. works with sudo command

Comment: Howe are you trying to install `traceroute`? You didn't show us the commands. Have you tried `sudo apt install traceroute`? `apt-cache search traceroute` shows many choices.

Comment: I had used sudo apt install traceroute. @waltinator. BTW it worked for me using sudo command for apt --fix-broken install

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE:

Your apt package manager is having trouble, you need to run:

```
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt autoclean
```

to check for broken installations and clean-up your apt package manager.

You should consider restarting your computer (depending on what apt fixed).

Now you can choose to use the tracepath package (preinstalled in linux) like this:

```
tracepath google.com
```

Or install Universe packages traceroute & net-tools with:

```
sudo apt install -y net-tools traceroute
```