# Certificate problems

Tags: ssl, wget, youtube-dl

Many shell applications are throwing SSL certificate errors. I'm not aware of anything that could have caused this. `apt`, Google Chrome, Discord all work fine.

Already tried: [Problem with certificates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420860/problem-with-certificates)

Examples:

**YouTube-dl**:
`<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)> (caused by URLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))`

**wget**:
`` ERROR: cannot verify www.google.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=GTS CA 1O1,O=Google Trust Services,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.google.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'. ``

**UPDATE**:

The time on my machine is correct. (I checked just to be sure)

`dpkg -l | grep cert` comes up with the following packages:

```
ii  ca-certificates                            20180409                                     all          Common CA certificates
ii  ca-certificates-java                       20180516ubuntu1~18.04.1                      all          Common CA certificates (JKS keystore)
ii  dirmngr                                    2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2                             amd64        GNU privacy guard - network certificate management service
ii  python3-certifi                            2018.1.18-2                                  all          root certificates for validating SSL certs and verifying TLS hosts (python3)
ii  ssl-cert                                   1.0.39                                       all          simple debconf wrapper for OpenSSL
```

**UPDATE 2**:

`which openssl` succesfully returns that OpenSSL is installed in `/usr/local/bin/openssl`.

`ldd $(which wget)` returns:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffda9b23000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f2edddd0000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f2eddbc8000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f2edd9a8000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f2edd710000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f2edd218000)
    libpsl.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5 (0x00007f2edd008000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2edcc10000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2edc9f0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2ede2d0000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f2edc670000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2edc468000)
```

**UPDATE 3**:

`dpkg -l | grep openssl` returns:

```
ii  openssl                                                     1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.4                                    amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility
ii  perl-openssl-defaults:amd64                                 3build1                                                     amd64        version compatibility baseline for Perl OpenSSL packages
```

**UPDATE 4**:

`sudo apt install --reinstall openssl` solved `wget`, but python apps like `youtube-dl` and `do-release-upgrade` are still reporting certificate issues.

**CONCLUSION**

Reinstalled Ubuntu

Comment: Is the time correct on your machine? Many times the time was incorrect on my laptop which would make the certs invalid.

Comment: Please show `dpkg -l | grep cert`

Comment: Yes, I even checked just to be sure. @Gordster

Comment: I updated the question with additional information, @nobody .

Comment: No ,wrong idea.  `which openssl` and `ldd $(which wget)`

Comment: I added the output of the commands to my question @nobody

Comment: Is `ca-certificates` installed on your computer?

Comment: @ThomasWard yes, even running `sudo update-ca-certificates` works without a problem.

Comment: I thing the Problem lies in your openssl in /usr/local/bin/ this is not the standart . `which openssl 
/usr/bin/openssl`

Comment: @nobody
What can I do about it? Should I try copying it over?

Comment: How did you install the openssl? `dpkg -l | grep openssl` And `tree /usr/local/` It seemed you have compilled something by your own.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be possible. I believe (I might be wrong) I compiled OpenSSL because I needed it for Kore, however I'm a C noob and might have done something wrong. I think I should be able to uninstall my version of OpenSSL and apt install it from Ubuntu's repositories, right? I'm not quite sure how I'd do that though. @nobody

Comment: @nobody nevermind ended up backing up my home directory (didn't have it set up as a separate partition) and installed Ubuntu 19.04 with a separate home partition

Answer (score 2):

The issue I found on my Ubuntu with Python was that I upgraded `pip install --upgrade certifi`... And then it took me hours trying to understand why things do not work...
Only once I had seen different versions here, that I started thinking in the right direction...

```
vitaliy@vitalnuc01:~/HANAClientsTutorial/python$ dpkg -l | grep python3-certifi
ii  python3-certifi                            2018.1.18-2                                         all          root certificates for validating SSL certs and verifying TLS hosts (python3)
vitaliy@vitalnuc01:~/HANAClientsTutorial/python$ pip3 search certifi
...
certifi (2020.4.5.1)                        - Python package for providing Mozilla's CA Bundle.
  INSTALLED: 2020.4.5.1 (latest)
...
```

So...

```
pip3 uninstall certifi
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-certifi
```

...and Python-based programs started working for me again.

And yes, I was close to reinstalling my Ubuntu as well :)